# Adding an app shortcut to android homescreen in an Ionic + Cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm writing an ionic app for android (in coffeescript and angular), and I want to add a shortcut to the app on the homescreen. Google didn't help, and [this cordova/phonegap](https://github.com/jorgecis/ShortcutPlugin/blob/4c2c01cc2473f4d3af8bfb6809f5d647c0078d72/README.md) plugin won't work either.

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Are you building an app using Ionic + Cordova or a web app using Ionic CSS framework ?

Comment: Then you must have an `.apk` file (generated by the build -> ionic build android). Just install this on your phone / tablet and you application will appear with its logo...

Comment: Native android behaviour puts the app in the app drawer, not on the home screen. An app can add itself to the home screen when it is opened. That's what I'm going for.

Answer (score 7):

Since ICS, you can do like this:

```
public void createShortCut(){
    Intent shortcutintent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    shortcutintent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.shortcutname));
    Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext, R.drawable.icon);
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(getApplicationContext, EnterActivity.class));
    sendBroadcast(shortcutintent);
}
```

Also add permission in AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Please also refer to the source code of launcher at: [this link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/master/src/com/android/launcher2/InstallShortcutReceiver.java)

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is valid for a Native android app. I was asking about an ionic app...

Comment: I think he is telling you to make a plugin that calls this natively.